# Calling a method after every 4 secs but tableview doesn't load meanwhile?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I already checked other solutions but nothing works.I need to hit a service after every 4sec so I am using

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.hitServiceUserChatMessageList), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

In this HitServiceUserChatMessageList I am reloading my tableView. I am able to hit the service after every 4sec but tableview doesn't show anything. It becomes blank.

Code for HitServiceUserChatMessageList

```
func hitServiceUserChatMessageList()
{
    //Start loader
    spinner.startAnimation(nil)
    spinner.hidden=false

    //Hit service for login
    let userName = GatyServiceManager.getValueForKey(Constants.key_UserEmailName) as! String
    let sessionID = GatyServiceManager.getValueForKey(Constants.Key_SessionId) as! String
    let userId = GatyServiceManager.getValueForKey(Constants.Key_SelectedUserForChat) as! String

    GatyServiceManager.sharedInstance().hitServiceUserMessageForChat(userName, sessionId: sessionID, userId:userId)
    { (success, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
            self.spinner.stopAnimation(nil)
            self.spinner.hidden=true
            self.array_ChatMessages.removeAllObjects()
            self.array_ChatMessages = GatyServiceManager.sharedInstance().array_allChats

            self.tableViewChat.reloadData()
            self.tableViewChat.scrollRowToVisible(self.array_ChatMessages.count - 1)
        }
        else
        {
            GatyServiceManager.sharedInstance().showAlertWithMsg(Constants.MSG_InvalidLogin)
            self.spinner.stopAnimation(nil)
            self.spinner.hidden=true
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `tableView.reloadData`?

Comment: Show us `hitServiceUserChatMessageList`.

Comment: @Willeke I updated the code. Please check.

Comment: Is `self.array_ChatMessages` what it should be?

Comment: @Willeke this array is used to update tableview. Each time service is hit after 4 sec interval the array count is zero.

Comment: That's why the tableview doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Willeke This is what I am not getting. Why array count is zero when it works fine for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Actually, I had two array self.array_ChatMessages and GatyServiceManager.sharedInstance().array_allChats.

GatyServiceManager.sharedInstance().array_allChats was getting data from server and then assigning it to self.array_ChatMessages.

Once, I execute the below two commands it delete data from both the arrays as both of them refer to same memory location.

```
self.array_ChatMessages.removeAllObjects()
        self.array_ChatMessages = GatyServiceManager.sharedInstance().array_allChats
```

Comment: You can remove `self.array_ChatMessages.removeAllObjects()`. When you assing a new value to `self.array_ChatMessages`, the old value is going to be deallocated.

Comment: Yes this is what I have done now. Thanks. Please upvote my ans if its correct